# Date format date-month-year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

I have a table which has a `datetime` column. I want to show date in date-month-year forma.I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert datetime column

```
select convert(varchar,datecolumn,103) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

Some datetime convertions:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '2016.10.23', 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '23.10.2016', 104) -- dd.mm.yyyy
SELECT convert(datetime, '23-10-2016', 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
/*  YYYY/MM/DD
    2015/07/11    */
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]
/*  YYYYMMDD
    20150711     */
```

-- SQL convert date string to datetime - time set to 00:00:00.000 or 12:00AM

```
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'07-10-2012',110)        -- Jul 10 2012 12:00AM
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'2012/07/10',111)        -- Jul 10 2012 12:00AM
PRINT CONVERT(datetime,'20120710',  112)        -- Jul 10 2012
```

You can learn all DateTime convertion from [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Comment: THIS! Converting sql dates is always confusing, thanks for the clear examples and link to more

Answer (score 0):

`FORMAT` can be used for this;

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MM-yyyy') --20-09-2021
```

in your case;

```
SELECT FORMAT(datetime, 'dd-MM-yyyy') AS datetime --20-09-2021
```

**Edit;**
Sorry to inform that I've just seen you mentioned **SQL Server 2008** this code works for **SQL Server 2012** for those who use 2012 and ends up in here!